# My attempt at $S = \overline{S}$ iff $S$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$E$ is a metric space and $S$ a set in it.

$\overline{S}$ denotes the closure of $S$. The definition for closure that I am using is:

> The closure of a set $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$. More explicitly:
>
> $\displaystyle \overline{A} = \bigcap_{i \in I} C_i $ , where for each $i \in I$ the set $C_i$ is closed in $E$ and $S \subset C_i$.
>
> $I$ is an index set.

Here is my write-up of a proof for the statement in the title. It seems a bit too facile and terse to me, so I wanted to ask for some feedback on its correctness.

---

**Proof:**

Suppose $S = \overline{S}$. The set $\overline{S}$ is an intersection of closed sets, and such intersections are always themselves closed. Therefore $S$ is closed.

Suppose now $S$ is closed. Since $S$ contains itself, it qualifies as $S = C_j$ for some $j \in I$.

$S$ is a subset of each $C_i$ so $S$ is necessarily in the intersection of all such sets, that is $S \subset \overline{S}$.

Next, for each $x \in \overline{S}$:

$x \in \overline{S} = \displaystyle \bigcap_{i \in I} C_i$ means $x \in C_i$ for each $i \in I$. In particular, $x \in C_j = S$. Therefore $\overline{S} \subset S$.

Hence $ \overline{S} = S$. We are done. $\blacksquare$.

---

Any thoughts or comments appreciated! Peace!

EDIT:

After José's feedback, I suppose the definition below is incorrect since it does not capture *every* possible closed set containing $S$:

> More explicitly:
>
> $\displaystyle \overline{A} = \bigcap_{i \in I} C_i $ , where for each $i \in I$ the set $C_i$ is closed in $E$ and $S \subset C_i$.
>
> $I$ is an index set.

The index set is not specified, so if there are infinitely many closed sets containing $S$ but $I$ is finite, we're missing some sets.

I think this ought to be the correct way to state it explicitly:

> $\overline{S} = \displaystyle \bigcap_{C \in A} C$
>
> where $ C = \{  X \subset E: X \text{ is closed and } S \subset X \} $

Comment: Your proof looks right to me.

Comment: @BenjaminSt. Thank you, I've made some corrections after José's feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the second part of that definition of $\overline A$ doesn't make sense (and it is not equivalent to the first part). If the definition was as in the second part, a set could have several distinct closures (a closure for each family of closed subsets of $E$ which contain $A$). The correct definition is the one from the first part: $\overline A$ is the intersection of *all* closed sets which contain $A$.

Other than that, your proof is fine.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I suppose you're right, I haven't specified the index set $I$ and for that reason I am not guaranteed to include *all* possible closed sets containing $S$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: What about this: $A = \displaystyle \bigcap_{C \in A} C $ where $A = \{ X \subset E : X \text{ is closed and } S \subset X \}$. Is this not equivalent to the first part?

Comment: Yes, if the first $A$ gets replaced with $\overline S$.

Comment: Oh darn yes, indeed. I'm going a little too fast here. Thank you for your feedback and help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Having the definition

$$\overline{S} = \bigcap \{C\mid C \text{ closed }, S \subseteq C\}$$

we see that 1. $\overline{S}$ is closed, as an intersection of closed sets and 2. $S \subseteq \overline{S}$ as all sets in the intersection contain $S$, hence so does their intersection.

If now $S=\overline{S}$, the first fact immediately implies $S$ is closed.

If $S$ is closed, $S$ is *one* of the sets that is in the defining intersection, so $\overline{S} \subseteq S$ and together with fact 2 we have $S=\overline{S}$ (having two inclusions).